# interactive debug console for Intellij and Eclipse like Pycharm has

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, pycharm

PyCharm has interactive debugging console:
[image: PyCharm interactive debugging console]

It allows you to check various things in runtime.
I've searched for similar functionality in Eclipse and in Intellij, and couldn't find. 
Does it exists there? Thanks

Comment: Seems "Evaluate Expression" is the option you're looking for: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html

Comment: Eclipse: [Java Scrapbook Page](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm)

Comment: Eclipse has something called a Debug Shell

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse** has Debug shell which you can use to write custom code and execute when you are in debug mode.

In **IntelliJ**, you can right click on any code that is in scope of debugging, evaluate expression and in that dialog you can keep custom code and evaluate.